# How to configure manifestPlaceholders?

Tags: android, gradle

I have 2 flavors and 2 buildType. ApplicationId is a constant and other is variable;

I need cofigure manifestPlaceholders value for this logic:

```
value = applicationId + (currentFlavor.equals(flavor2) ? "c" : "") + (currentBuild.equals(buildType.debug) ? "dev" : "")
manifestPlaceholders = [pakackage:value]
```

That is, for flavor2 will be added the suffix "c" for the debug build will be added as the suffix "dev". It's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have builds with different applicationIds based on flavor and build types

```
productFlavors {
    flavor2 {
        applicationIdSuffix ".c"
    }
    ...
}


buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    release{
    }
}
```

These builds will be generated:

- flavor2Debug:   yourApplicationId.c.dev
- flavor2Release: yourApplicationId.c
- flavor1Debug:   yourApplicationId.dev
- flavor1Release: yourApplicationId

Comment: That need. Thx!